# Checking which node in a VerneMQ cluster a client is connected to

Tags: mqtt-vernemq

Is there a way to check which node in a VerneMQ cluster a client is connected to short of using something like WireShark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo vmq-admin session show --client_id=ClientID --node
```

should give you what you need. The session command is cluster-aware.

Look up further options with --help

```
sudo vmq-admin session show --help
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vmq-admin cluster show
Last login: xxxxx
+------------------+-------+
|       Node       |Running|
+------------------+-------+
|VerneMQ@1.1.1.1| true  |
|VerneMQ@1.1.1.2| true  |
+------------------+-------+
```